# How to name a Rails resource that is an adjective or preposition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord, activeresource

I'm teaching kids how to do a particular app in Rails and it requires a resource that is about somebody being responsible for someone else. For example, here are 2 models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :responsible_fors, class_name: 'ResponsibleFor', foreign_key: 'responsible_by_ user_id'
  has_many :responsible_for_people, through: :responsible_fors
  has_many :responsible_bys, class_name: 'ResponsibleFor', foreign_key: 'responsible_for_user_id'
  has_many :responsible_by_people, through: :responsible_bys
end
class ResponsibleFor < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :relationship, :responsible_by_id, :responsible_for_id
  belongs_to :responsible_by, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :responsible_for, class_name: 'User'
end
```

I haven't tested this specific code above, but the concept makes sense to me... Though `responsible` and `responsible for` are an adjective and preposition, respectively, not a noun as resources in Rails are supposed to be. Is there a better way to do this? Will Rails' pluralization or other manipulations scramble this up in other ways? Is there a better noun?

Comment: You may have to set a `source` after your `through` key. So as an example, you should have `has_many :responsible_for_people, through: :responsible_fors, source: responsible_for`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're going to have any issues with Rails and pluralize:

```
1.9.3p385 :023 > "responsible_for".pluralize
=> "responsible_fors" 
1.9.3p385 :024 > _.singularize
=> "responsible_for"
```

That said, I would just go with:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :responsibilities
  has_many :stakeholders, through: :responsibilities
  has_many :responsible_parties, through: responsibilities
end

class Responsibility < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :relationship, :stakeholder_user_id, :responsible_party_user_id
  belongs_to :stakeholder
  belongs_to :responsible_party
end
```

I'm not sure that this code runs (I'd be shocked if it does), but this is what I would use for naming.